# Replacing a file tree component in Java Swing to another

Tags: java, swing, data-structures, filesystems, jtree

I need help using java swing to replace the dummy file tree on the left side of the GUI in SB_Administrator.java to the the more advanced java tree of FileTree.java.

I am currently using windowBuilder in Eclipse.

Thanks in advance for your help

SB_Administrator.java

```
        // Get the root node of the tree
        DefaultMutableTreeNode rootSess = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) tree.getModel().getRoot();
        //rootSess.setUserObject(sess);     // remember the Session in it


        splitPane.setLeftComponent(tree);

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        splitPane.setRightComponent(tabbedPane);
    }

}
```

FileTree.java

............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new `FileTree` object
2. Give as parameter a `File` object (e.q. `new File("root_path")`)
3. Replace your old tree `splitPane.setLeftComponent(tree)` with the new tree `splitPane.setLeftComponent(fileTree)`

```
FileTree fileTree = new FileTree(new File("./"));
splitPane.setLeftComponent(fileTree);
```